# Converting All Apache Rewrite Rules to Nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have a variety of apache rewrite rules that I've been trying to convert to nginx without much success.   I either get a configuration error, or it doesn't properly rewrite.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*) /$2?lang=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/categories/(.*) /index.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/category-(.*) /index.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/product-(.*) /product.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/auction-(.*) /auction.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/browse-(.*) /browse.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/browse /browse.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/item-(.*) /item.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/auctions/([0-9]+) /auction.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/help/faq/([0-9]+) /help/faq.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/deal-([0-9]+) /deals/deal.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/gameplay/play-(.*) /gameplay/game_details.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /$1/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal config block that would need to be modified according to your configurations, also you need to add the `php` capturing block at the end

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;
  index index.php;

  #rewrites start here
  rewrite ^/([a-z]{2})/?$       /index.php?lang=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)     /$2?lang=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/categories/(.*)     /index.php?cat=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/category-(.*)       /index.php?cat=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/product-(.*)        /product.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/auction-(.*)        /auction.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/browse-(.*)         /browse.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/browse              /browse.php$is_args$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/item-(.*)           /item.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/auctions/([0-9]+)   /auction.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/help/faq/([0-9]+)   /help/faq.php?cat=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/deal-([0-9]+)       /deals/deal.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
  rewrite ^/gameplay/play-(.*)  /gameplay/game_details.php?name=$1&$query_string last;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.   This is pretty much what I ended up with after a lot of trial and error.